# Data binding with EF6 in winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, data-binding, entity-framework-6

I have 2 Gridviews first one should bind to the user list from the EF6 DB first and when selecting a user another grid should bind to the user roles. In the past wit EF4 and after this kind of binding I were be able to make any changes on the 2 gridviews as I want and finally I can call the context SaveChanges() method to save all these changes. But now with EF6 I tried to delete records from the user roles Gridview and call SaveChanges() but nothing occurs.
This this the used C# Code

```
public partial class RadForm2 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    Model.MomenERPEntities ctx = new Model.MomenERPEntities(AppConfig.MomenERPEntitiesConnectionString);
    public RadForm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindUsers();
    }

    private void BindUsers()
    {
        ctx.Users.Load();
        userBindingSource.DataSource = ctx.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
    }

    private void userBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (userBindingSource.Current != null && userBindingSource.Current is User)
        {
            userRoleBindingSource.DataSource = (userBindingSource.Current as User).UserRoles;
        }
    }

    private void radButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var updates = ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(ee => ee.State == EntityState.Deleted);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow the instructions here: [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx). This step-by-step walkthrough shows how to bind POCO types to Window Forms (WinForms) controls in a “master-detail" form. The application uses Entity Framework to populate objects with data from the database, track changes, and persist data to the database.

Comment: Thanks **Reza Aghaei** your comment was very helpful.